# waiting for dbus address to appear error

Tags: python-3, raspberry-pi-os, raspberry-pi-os-bullseye, raspberry-pi-os-buster

I'm trying to run my Python executable on startup but I'm getting an error (waiting for dbus address to appear error) continuously it can't stop. Is there any way to stop I tried to update and upgrade also not helpful.

Comment: dbus-daemon: /home/pi/EVA/libdbus-1.so.3: version `LIBDBUS_PRIVATE_1.12.24' not found (required by dbus-daemon)
waiting for dbus address to appear
waiting for dbus address to appear
waiting for dbus address to appear
waiting for dbus address to appear
waiting for dbus address to appear

Comment: please put all information into the question ... use the edit button for that ... do not use a comment